# How can i make mouse click on form1 over an image rectangle/area?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a paint event of form1.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bmp != null)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0,50,50);
        }
```

And a form1 click event.

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cast to MouseEventArgs
        MouseEventArgs mouse = (MouseEventArgs)e;

        // If mouse is within image
        if (mouse.X >= 0 && mouse.Y >= 0 && mouse.X < 0 + bmp.Width && mouse.Y < 0 + bmp.Height)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }
    }
```

But in this case when i click on the image at 0,0 it will show the messagebox but also if i click out of the  image area.
I need that it will show the messagebox only if i clicked on the image area and borders. Even if i click on the edge of the image border it will show the messagebox and also if i click somewhere on the image it self. Anywhere out the image area won't display the messagebox.

Comment: just an idea why cannot you implement image box click event?

Comment: I can use pictureBox good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Rectangle rec;
        Bitmap bmp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(@"YourImageUrlHere");
            rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bmp != null)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, rec);
        }

        //private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    dont use this....
        //}

        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(rec.Contains(e.Location))
                MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
```